# alphabetic binary search tree BST algorithm

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, alphabetical

I want to declare a class of an alphabetic BST where you can store the nodes by Name -strings or char array-. what is the best algorithm for insertion method in order to have the best search time and have a ideal case BST.
also good to remind that names are not all in same length and may start with same words, they will not be sorted before entering the BST.

Comment: You algorithm for insertion is the same algorithm for using integers.  Change the data type, not the algorithm.  Your bottleneck may be string comparison.  There are algorithms for efficient string comparisons, search the internet.

Comment: You may want to use a different data structure than a BST for handling strings.  For example, using a B-Tree with 26 elements per page (one for each letter) would speed up comparisons by only comparing a single character rather than the entire string.

Comment: unordered map might be good... Especially if you achieve a perfect hash.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion is fast in balanced binary search trees, so either implement a Red-Black tree or an AVL tree. You may also go for B-Trees if you wish to.

Next, you need to look at what to store in a node of the BST. In your case, store the `string` or `char array`. To compare two keys, you already have functions defined for both `string` and `char array`, i.e [`string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) and [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) respectively.

These two things are all you need to do what you asked, a balanced BST and a datatype for nodes which is comparable.